Is this valid usage of 'with' for TelegramClient and start()?
I want to use the context manager with and to pass the password to the start() at the same time. I think this can be done because in the documentation of the start() function it is written:
"""
Returns
   This `TelegramClient`, so initialization
   can be chained with ``.start()``."""

This code works as expected, but I dont find similar usage of with and start() in the telethon examples from documentation.
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = 1111111111
api_hash = 1111111111
password = 1111111111

session = 'my_session'
client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash,
                        system_version="4.16.30-vxCUSTOM")

with client.start(password=password):
    client.run_until_disconnected()


The client.start function must be returning a class instance that can be used as a context manager - i.e., something that implements both __enter__ and __exit__ dunder functions.
Typically, the __exit__ function will perform some kind of "clean up".
It's quite possible that any "clean up" is done in the class's implementation of __del__ but if it's done during __exit__ then the context manager approach would be preferred.
The author of this module shows contact details on the PyPI page. Perhaps you should ask him/her

Yes, the documentation simply states that client.start returns client (for whatever instance of TelegramClient is bound to the name client).
That means
client.start()
with client:
    ...

means the same thing as
with client.start():
    ...


The start() function returns not just a client, but an already running (connected) client.  From documentation: "Starting the client is as easy as calling client.start()" and "Starting using a context manager (this calls start()): with client:"
So I doubt my code, because there is a gap between start() and 'with' where client working outside of the context manager.

You're correct that in v1 if start fails, the context manager won't be reached and disconnect won't be called. But if start failed, it's likely to be a network error anyway (so if you couldn't connect, there's no need to disconnect)

The gap doesn't matter if you don't take the opportunity to explicitly execute code in that gap. with client.start() isn't more "atomic" in any sense.

Now I understand what my mistake was. I thought that "with" also works as a context manager for asynchronous events and  async loop. But now I understand that this is only a context manager for connection to telegram server.
